# UI router change templateUrl on click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Im trying to create a dynamic UI router when everytime you click a button it needs to return the templateUrl with the $stateParams.currentFloor changes only so it can get updated in the view on the screen.

Currently I have:

My setup:

```
app.config(function ($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            views: {
                "menu-view": {
                    templateUrl: 'partials/menu.html'
                },
                "map-view": {
                    controller: 'mapViewController',
                    templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
                        return 'partials/floors/floor-' +  $stateParams.currentFloor + '.html'
                    }
                }
            }
        })
});
```

My controller what needs to hold the data and pass it in the templateUrl function

```
app.controller('mapViewController', function ($scope, $stateParams) {
    $scope.currentFloor = $stateParams.currentFloor;
    $scope.currentFloor = 1;
    $scope.addOne = function () {
        $scope.currentFloor = $scope.currentFloor + 1;
        return $stateParams.currentFloor = $scope.currentFloor;
    };
});
```

And just simple a function what adds +1 to the scope everytime on a click

```
<button ng-click="addOne()"></button>
```

I think I'm pretty close but I have a hard time passing the data from my controller to the function what needs to change the templateUrl

Comment: Can you do a plunker please? You'll need to reload the state after you change state params

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/1xaMwcoyfAlz4zcE96TO?p=preview can't even get the plunker getting to work. I think it is something with the # state

Comment: You work with angular 2 ?

Comment: Oh men, I didn't even see I quik added angular 2. My bad changing it now

Comment: I succeed to make it work I'll write an answer

Comment: Oh great! I still trying on my own computer but sadly I have not made any progress yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96661/discussion-between-lg-and-dennis).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the updated plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/yCKJ1JFp7dMWd6wFtrak?p=preview)

One possible solution :

```
 var app = angular.module('testTool', ['ui.router'])

  .config(function($urlRouterProvider, $stateProvider) {

     $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/1');

     $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/:currentFloor',
            views: {
                "menu-view": {
                 templateUrl: 'menu.html'
                 },
            "map-view": {
                templateUrl: function ($stateParams) {
                          return 'floor-' +  $stateParams.currentFloor + '.html'
                },
            controller: 'mapViewController'
         }, 
       }
      })
  })

  .controller('mapViewController', function($scope, $stateParams, $state) {

      $scope.addOne = function() {

          $state.go('home', {currentFloor : parseInt($stateParams.currentFloor) + 1}, {reload: true})

      };
  });
```

Add param 'currentFloor in url params `(url:'/:currentFloor')`. Then reload state with this params : `$state.go('home', {currentFloor : 2}, {reload: true})`

Option `reload:true` is important for ui router reload the state when your are on the same state.

I suggest you to use resolve function if you need to do some work between $stateParams and object in your scope.

Comment: Wow impressive stuff, thanks alot this is exacly what I want to achieve!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `$state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true})` after changing $stateParams.

Comment: Nope doesn't work, I can't even get the all the data what is inside the #$scope in the templateUrl function

Comment: and if you pass the params like this ```$state.go($state.current, {yourParam: yourData }, {reload: true})```